Why does the BSWAP x86-64 instruction have latency 2 on modern Intel processors?
The 64-bit BSWAP instruction is listed to have a latency of 2 cycles on both uops.info and in Agner Fog's instruction tables on modern Intel architectures like Broadwell, Cannon Lake, Ice Lake, etc. On AMD this instruction has been a single-cycle latency instruction for a very, very long time according to these sources.
However, I can't imagine any reason as to why this instruction would need 2 cycles of latency on Intel. It doesn't compute anything, it is a zero-gate instruction: it is literally just a set of 64 wires crossing in a particular pattern to reverse the order of the bytes in the register.
What is the technical reason this is so? Or is the latency reading incorrect on both uops.info and Agner Fog?

bswap r32 is 1*p06, whereas bswap r64 is 1*p1 + 1*p06.  p1 has shifters.  I strongly suspect that bswap r64 is implemented by byte-swapping the two 32-bit register halves and then rotating the whole thing by 32 places.  This might require less die space than a full 64-bit bswap circuit as half the circuit is reused for the 32-bit bswap.  But who knows for sure?

@fuz "But who knows for sure?" Possibly an Intel engineer who stumbles across this question... or a very motivated person with a very good microscope :)

it is literally just a set of 64 wires - muxing different outputs according to ALU control inputs (which specify the operand size) is not a lot easier than some other operations.  For an adder, the operand-size just controls when you chop off the result; the low part is always the same.  Still, 2 possible sources for each bit instead of 1 is not a huge deal; the SIMD shuffle units have way more complexity.  (If byte-swapping throughput is a problem, use SSE3 pshufb for a small buffer if you can.)

But yeah, I agree with fuz that we can infer a lot from the uop port breakdowns and what other execution units are on those ports.  Good idea that the second uop might just be a rotate, with the first uop being basically two 32-bit bswaps in parallel.
